# Phone app for spoken definitions while reading

Tags: android, ios, speech-recognition, dictionary

When I read on my Kindle, I can simply highlight a word to get its definition.  When I read a paper book, this doesn't work. I'm looking for an app on my phone that allows the following: (1) I ask it for the definition of a word; (2) it speaks the definition to me. This allows me to only minimally interrupt the flow of my reading.

I will note that I've tried [Siri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siri), the Merriam-Webster dictionary app, and [Google Now](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Now). None of these works very well for this (try any of them with the word "turophile").

Some things that are important to me:

- Should work on both iOS and Android;
- Ideally accepts lots of esoteric words (like turophile);
- Ideally is "always on" and can be cued by saying some variant of "define [word]" (like Google's "OK Google");
- Best would be cheap/free.

Comment: Tough one. All these apps use voice recognition algorithms based on the likelihood of words appearing in common language, but you want to look up *uncommon* words. Such an app would need the ability for you to spell the word.

Comment: Googling just doesn't cut it?

Comment: Google's voice recognition seems to work fine with obscure words like turophile. Maybe it's gotten better over the years?